# ggplot2 cuts off parts of my figure when zooming in

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a figure in gglot2 that looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFHKW.png).

However, I seem right now to have a trade off between having all the squares small like ... Or zooming in on the squares and having parts cut
[both displayed here as I may not add more pictures, yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkOv4.png)

My code is as follow

```
if (!require('ggplot2')) install.packages('ggplot2'); library('ggplot2')


Odds <- c(1.2,1,0.97,1,1.38,0.95,0.85,0.95)
x <- c(5,3.5,0,-3.5,-5,-3.5,0,3.5)
y <- c(0,3.5,5,3.5,0,-3.5,-5,-3.5)

summed <- data.frame(Odds,x,y)
d <- qplot(x, y, data=summed, colour =Odds)
d + theme_classic(base_size = 14) + geom_point(size = 30, shape=15) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high = "black") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL)
```

I hope some of you can help me.

Comment: maybe add `expand_limits(x =c(-6,6), y =c(-6,6))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GGplot grants a certain "bleeding" or "breathing" around plot area. The size of your geom_point simply goes beyond that space. 
A solution is to set custom limits to the ploting area. Try this:

```
    d <-qplot(x, y, data=summed, color =Odds)
    d + theme_classic(base_size = 14) + geom_point(size = 30, shape=15) +
         scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high = "black") +
         ylab("") +
         xlab("") +
         scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL) + 
         scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL) +
         theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + ## Optional. Ensures you get a square shaped plot
         expand_limits(x =c(min(x) - 1, max(x) + 1), ## Expands the limits, reads from your predefined "x" and "y" objects.
                       y =c(min(y)-1, max(y) +1))
```